# Where to put business rules for querying when using NHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Still new to NHibernate. I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2 and the Linq provider.

I am wondering where I should put my business rule logic. For example, I have an entity called Service with DateTime property. In my web app, I only ever want to display/work with services whose DataTime is less than 4 weeks away. Where should I put that rule?

I started out building a ServiceRepository with a IEnumerable GetServices() method that encapsulated that logic, thinking "Oh! Everytime I need a service, I'll go to that method!"

Of course, problems show up when I need to load child objects of my services. I don't want a lot of permutations of the same method in my repository when querying my database. In fact I really don't want to use repositories at all, because I'm trying very hard to heed [Ayende's Advice](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/17/repository-is-the-new-singleton.aspx), since I'm still new to NHibernate.

I like the idea of having objects that specify what I need from the database, and I could encapsulate the business rule within it. The linq part of it is what is throwing me off, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need additional methods to "load child objects". You can rely on relationships and lazy loading for that.

With that, your original design is valid.

Comment: Valid, but probably not efficient. If I know ahead of time what I need, I can help NHibernate construct a single query instead of N+1 queries.

Comment: You can avoid the N+1 problem without changing the queries. See, for example, http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch. There's also caching, etc.

Comment: Ok. But, I am running into session is closed problems, when Child object properties are accessed in my view (asp.net mvc).

Comment: That's because you're managing your session incorrectly. You should open it when the request begins, close it when it ends.

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing. That wasn't the problem. The problem was that I was keeping entities around for multiple requests and when I tried to access them later, they got angry because their session had been closed.

Comment: That's not optimal either. Use DTOs for long conversation storage.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Fabio Maulo's [Enhanced Query Object](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/enhanced-query-object.html). This demonstrates a nice way to encapsulate NHibernate queries while allowing for a great deal of flexibility in how they are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It will good if you mention your business logic in BLL and your project structure must be like :

1. BLL(Business Logic Layer).
   it contains
   interface,
   services,
   models
2. DLL(Dynmic link libery).
   it contains 
   Repsitory,
   Nhibernate mapping class

3.Website.
(Add BLL,DLL refernce )